# rails 3.1 select_tag usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Ive got a select_tag field at the top of a page and trying to get the selected option to change the content on the page based on the users selection.

Im a learner and have found pieces of information around but without detailed examples and good explanations on how to best approach and implement.

**The scenario is as follows:**
I have a belongs_to association between a project and documents and in one of my views which lists documents, I want to only show all the documents that belong to the currently selected project in the select tag.

Passing the selected project's id to the documents index action which only shows documents for a specified project id via a link_to tag came to mind. This would thus refresh the page with the correct documents in the view but I believe that is not the correct way to do it and that I cant use link_to tags as options in a select_tag. Can anyone help and offer an example?

Comment: Do you know the available options that may be chosen? If so, and there are only a few, link_to's would do it. You can also do a select_tag with a pull down.

Comment: The available options vary according to the projects created by the user. basically the user can create projects and also create documents that belong to projects. The reason I want to use the select_tag is because when im looking at the documents, I only want to be looking at the documents based on the selected project. I have the select_tag in a partial as I need it to show in various views as I have various other items that belong to specific projects.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller:

```
def index
  if params[:project]
    @documents = Document.where(:project => params[:project]
  else
    @projects = Project.all
  end
end
```

In your form/view:

```
<%= form_tag 'projects', :method => :get do %>
  <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@projects, :id, :name)
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>

<% if @documents %>
  <%= @documents.each do |d| %>
    ....
  <% end >
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was hoping to get away without the need for a form with a submit tag, any idea how I could implement this using a select_tag instead?

Comment: options_from_collection_for_select is basically a select_tag. In either case, you'll need to submit the select info to get the response you want. Neither will automatically update your page, unless you do something in Javascript/Ajax.

Comment: okay thank you. Are you able to show me an example of how I could go about implementing this using Javascript/Ajax with a select_tag?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the form.select method and options_for_select as in

```
f.select :attribute, options_for_select(@array, default_value)
```

and in your controller you should create or update using the submitted parameter

```
n = record.new(:attribute => params[:attribute])
```

have fun

Comment: is there a way to achieve this without using a form?

Comment: yes there is also this isn't really common.. you could call a custom action in a controller wich creates a new record with prefixed value's although I don't see the point in not wanting forms? use hidden fields if you dont want it to be visible :)